# Get the column index as a value when value exists

Tags: python, pandas

I need do create some additional columns to my table or separate table based on following:

I have a table

[image]

and I need to create additional columns where the column indexes (names of columns) will be inserted as values. Like this:

[image]

How to do it in pandas? Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need matched columns only for `1` values:

```
df = (df.set_index('name')
        .eq(1)
        .dot(df.columns[1:].astype(str) + ',')
        .str.rstrip(',')
        .str.split(',', expand=True)
        .add_prefix('c')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
```

**Explanation**:

Idea is create boolean mask with `True` for values which are replaced by columns names - so compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) by `1` and used matrix multiplication by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by all columns without first with added separator. Then remove last traling separator by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for new column, changed columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html).

Another solution:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name').eq(1).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), index=df1.index).add_prefix('c').reset_index()
```

Comment: I just need to have a zoomed look to the code and understand it. Big, big thanks!!