# Order values horizontally within a group. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

A couple weeks ago I asked a question about masking nans in row and only leave existing values [Get the column index as a value when value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536009/get-the-column-index-as-a-value-when-value-exists)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Xru.png)

I got an excellent solution provided  by @jezrael (you can find it to the link above).

To addition to the original task i need to order values (ascending) based on their weights in separate table.

I will reformulate the task from beginning.

I have 2 tables:

[image]

and

[image]

I need to get a final table as we got in previous solution but with ordered values based on their weights like this

[image]

is it possible to incorporate the reordering code  line to the existing code? or reorder then after? How to do it based on the table apart?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide your data in a form that can be copied (as below), never as pictures.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1a': [1] * 4 + [None] * 12,
    '3f': [None] * 5 + [1] * 2 + [None] * 9,
    '5y': [None] * 11 + [1] * 3 + [None] * 2,
    't6': [None] * 7 + [1, 1,] + [None] * 7,
    '7j': [None] * 14 + [1, 1]},
    index=range(1, 17)).T
weights = pd.Series([.5, .4, .34, .54, .12, .45, .18, .45, .34, .19, .2, .18, .12, .56, .78, .98],
                    index=range(1, 17))
```

This solution multiplies the dataframe (boolean indicators) by the weights, then uses a list comprehension to sort each row of the result (after first dropping nulls) and take the index.  A DataFrame is created from the result.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        [row.dropna().sort_values().index.tolist() 
         for _, row in df.mul(weights).iterrows()], 
        index=df.index)
df2.columns = ['c{}'.format(n + 1) for n in range(df2.shape[1])]
>>> df2
    c1  c2  c3  c4
1a   3   2   1   4
3f   7   6 NaN NaN
5y  13  12  14 NaN
7j  15  16 NaN NaN
t6   9   8 NaN NaN
```

`df.mul(weights)` results in the following dataframe:

```
    1    2     3     4   5     6     7     8     9   10  11    12    13    14    15    16 
1a  0.5  0.4  0.34  0.54 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 
3f  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  0.45  0.18   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5y  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN  0.18  0.12  0.56   NaN   NaN
7j  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.78  0.98
t6  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN   NaN  0.45  0.34 NaN NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I then iterate over each of these rows using [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), drop the NaNs, and sort the result and take the sorted index.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. It works for the sample indeed. The second part (for _, row in df.mul(s).iterrows()) - what does it actually do? Just multiplying weights? I do not understand itterows() operator :(

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I would just like to ask you to help me to split the code in two, where first it drop nans and then (2) sort values. When I run the full code for real data I got a a tabel with 2 rows and cant understand where the error is.

Comment: hmm, when it drops nans it just leaves consecutive values, however values can exist between nans as well

Comment: It has to drop the NaNs by row, as it does in the code above. See this for example: `pd.Series([1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3]).dropna()`

Comment: It wors, @Alexander. Thank you! I just  made a confuse with indexes and my "weights" initially were as dataframe and not series. Now it is ok!